# Keyboard USB to USB 2.4Ghz RF conversion

Tags: usb, rf

Where to find information about "2.4Ghz" keyboards and mouses protocols? I'm investigating possibilities of creating (or buying, if such thing exists) of universal USB>2.4Ghz rf/ 2.4Ghz rf>USB for keyboard.

Comment: Shopping questions are not allowed here, which is likely why there are downvotes. You haven't shown any prior research. If you google, you will find information.

Comment: -1 for No research effort. No background info given. Not a design question. Not an objective question. Indeed a shopping question. All of the above not allowed on SE!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear because of two protocols involved: 2.4GHz protocol (which has nothing to do with whether the device is a mouse or keyboard) and USB. The wireless protocol can be proprietary or bluetooth or anything in between.

What you're basically trying to do is to use a microcontroller with some 2.4GHz transceiver and USB host capability to transmit the USB information on the air. The 2.4GHz can be any protocol really, as long as it meets the timing specifications for the mouse.

There is only one issue with all this, powering the mouse or keyboard (and the transmitter board itself). Usually the solution is to use a mouse or keyboard that already wireless for smallest size, else you need to add a battery.

Comment: Most of the wireless keyboard / mice from a product-line order than 4-5 years, are very likely to be proprietary as Gustavo wrote. Bluetooth based keyboard and mice are relatively more recent additions, and were mostly targeted towards mobile devices (s.a. Smartphones, though exceptions exist).

Answer (score 1):

## Rationale

Mice and keyboards, which come with dedicated dongles don't require any configuration from the user.

1. She plugs the dedicated dongle in.
2. The dongle presents itself as a USB human interface device to the OS. It's transparent to the OS whether it's wired or wireless.

The over-the-air communication protocol is usually Bluetooth.  But the dedicated dongle can't be configured and the mouse is not discoverable.  So, the Bluetooth-ness is hidden and not accessible.

The rationale behind having a dedicated dongle is that the user doesn't have to discover and pair Bluetooth devices.  Many non-techies struggle with configuring Bluetooth.

## Approach

Use actual non-committed Bluetooth mice and keyboards (they usually come without dongles).  Use a general-purpose Bluetooth dongle.  Pair them.  Now you have a dongle, which is not hard-committed to a particular peripheral.

Comment: The thing is I want to use some particular wired USB HID device wirelessly (gaming keypad), not just any HID device